# Android BLE BluetoothGattService is null

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use the android app to connecting the BLE device 
 the code

```html
   mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);

   BluetoothGattService bluetoothservice=mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0003cdd0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b0131"));
```

the result is error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID)' on a null object reference

because i want get the service by bluetoothgatt not callback(if get service from  mGattCallback is ok)

thanks

Comment: You should probably wait until the device connects, then do a service discovery. After this you can call `getService`.

Comment: @shawnjone Did you solve this problem?  I am facing the same issue.